# Registrar nombre de tabla borrada en Oracle

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

tengo que hacer un trigger en oracle que cuando un usuario borre una tabla de la base de datos quede registrado en una tabla previamente creada, el usuario, la fecha y el nombre de la tabla borrada.
He creado el trigger para que realice lo que expongo.
Pero no se como hacer para que en el registro aparezca el nombre de la tabla borrada.
Para el usuario es **user**, para la fecha es **sysdate**, pero para la tabla no lo sé.
Me podéis ayudar?

El código que tengo es este:

```
CREATE TABLE ctrTablasB
(
 usuario VARCHAR2(30),
 momento DATE,
 tabla VARCHAR2(30)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER registro_borrado
AFTER drop ON database

BEGIN
            INSERT INTO ctrtablasb values (
            user,sysdate, /*aquí quiero que aparezca el nombre de la tabla borrada en la base de datos*/ ; 
        
END registro_borrado;
```

Comment: Serviría de mucho que colocaras el código de ese script.

Comment: Sin nada mas de apoyo no se te puede ayudar, edita tu pregunta y añade lo que has intentado.

Comment: He modificado la pregunta añadiendo el código. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya he dado con la solución, es la siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER registro_borrado
AFTER DROP ON database

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ctrtablasb values ( 
   user,sysdate, ora_dict_obj_name);
     
END registro_borrado;
```